# Git diff of commits introduced in a branch

Tags: git, branch, diff

I have different old branches I want to delete but I want to see the commits/diff I originally introduced in the branch at that time.

I don't want the diff between "master" and "branch" but all the unified commits introduced in that branch as a single diff.

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "as a single diff" at the end? Do you want a file diff (i.e. line additions/deletions) or a commits list, I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the diff or list of commits "from" a branch which is already merged into your `master`, like this

```
A---B---F---G---H---I---J <<< master <<< HEAD
     \         /
      C---D---E <<< branch-a
```

Here, `H` is the merge commit, and `B` the commit `branch-a` branched from.

If you do

```
git diff master branch-a
```

as you noted, you won't get the diff for the list of commits on `branch-a`, but the for accumulated changes that happened since the merge commit, which is entirely different.

So you'd have to diff between the tip of `branch-a` (`E`) and the [merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) between the two branches (`B`) :

```
git diff `git merge-base branch-a master` branch-a
```

...which, as usefully noted by jthill [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526432/git-diff-of-commits-introduced-in-a-branch#comment97763153_55526535), can be a bit less verbose with the special [three-dots syntax](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection), to the same effect :

```
git diff master...branch-a
```

And of course you can add here any options you need to display code diffs or file lists, in the format you want. Maybe tell us more in case of a specific format.

But alternatively you could also want to get the list of commits, and it wouldn't be much more difficult to extract, you could do

```
git log `git merge-base branch-a master`..branch-a
```

(mind the *two* dots to make it a range, not to be confused with above three-dots)

---

Also, for any remaining doubts, check the very useful [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) on revisions.

Comment: This is such a common usage that git diff has syntax for it: `git diff master...branch-a` (three dots).  See `git help diff` and search for three dots.

Comment: @jthill I've read about it a couple of times but never think of it when I need it. Thanks for the reminder!